# Error al pasar parametro a ruta get de laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Tengo la siguiente ruta, al querer cargar la vista desde el controlador no se me cargan bien los estilos y en el log me sale un mensaje asi:

> production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from `entidades`)

Sin embargo, si le quito el parámetro funciona a la perfección. En el controlador lo único que hago es hacer una petición a un api y tanto con parámetro como sin él hace la misma petición.

```php
Route::group(['prefix'=>'facturas'], function (){
    Route::get('/pagarFactura/{id}', [
        'uses' => 'FacturasController@pagarFactura',
        'as' => 'pagarFactura'
    ]);
]);
```

Comment: Muestra cómo defines la función `pagarFactura` en `FacturasController`.

Comment: ```public function pagarFactura($idFactura){}``` así la defino

Comment: Bueno, no tiene sentido con el mensaje de error que muestras, que es de una consulta a base de datos. ¿Estás seguro de ese log es de cuando accedes a esa ruta?¿No será un log viejo o de otra parte de tu aplicación?

Comment: si estoy completamente seguro que es el error correcto

Answer (score 0):

Tu error no es por la variable, el error `production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'forge'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from`entidades`)`te esta diciendo que el usuario `"forge"` no tiene acceso a la base de datos, revisa que tu usuario y contraseña esten correctos y de hecho tu base de datos no necesita contraseña, eso lo puedes configurar en el archivo `.env`

Comment: Gracias pero el resto de la aplicación funciona sin problema accediendo a la misma base de datos

Comment: ¿Puedes subir el fragmento de código que te genera el error (del controlador)? Para determinar la fuente del error

Comment: este seria mi codigo en el controlador
 ```$user=Auth::user();
     $entidad=$user->Entidad;
     $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client(['http_errors' => 
     false,'exceptions'=>false,'verify'=>false]);
     $uri = $entidad->IP . ":" . $entidad->puerto . $entidad->instancia .
     "fact_lin?filter[fact]=".$idFactura."&api_key=".$entidad->api_key;
      $res=json_decode($client->request('GET',$uri, 
      ['connect_timeout'=>5,'timeout'=>5])->getBody()->getContents());
      return view('facturas.detalleFactura')->with('usuario',$user)- 
      >with('fecha',Carbon::now());```